# File Upload using Spring WebFlow 2.4.0, parameter not binded

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-webflow

I'm using Spring Framework 4.1.5, Spring Security 4.0.0.RC2, Spring Webflow 2.4.0.RELEASE and Tomcat 8.0.15.

I followed the example in the webflow [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/reference/html/actions.html), but I can't get the file in my form bean.

The form

```
    <form:form action="${flowExecutionUrl}" method="post" commandName="fileForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <form:input type="file" value="" path="multipartFileUpload"/>
        <button type="submit" name="_eventId_forward"><spring:message code="signup.forward"/></button>
        <sec:csrfInput/>
    </form:form>
```

The form bean

```
public class FileForm implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private transient MultipartFile multipartFileUpload;

    public MultipartFile getMultipartFileUpload() {
        return multipartFileUpload;
    }

    public void setMultipartFileUpload(final MultipartFile multipartFileUpload) {
        this.multipartFileUpload = multipartFileUpload;
    }
}
```

The flow

```
<view-state id="companyLogo" view="signup/company-logo" model="fileForm">
    <var name="fileForm" class="it.openex.pmcommonw.form.FileForm"/>
    <transition on="back" to="chooseProfile" bind="false" validate="false"/>
    <transition on="forward" to="companyInfo">
        <evaluate expression="userCommonBean.uploadImage(fileForm)"/>
    </transition>
</view-state>
```

The backing object

```
@Component
public class UserCommonBean {    
    public static void uploadImage(final FileForm fileForm) throws IOException, ServletException {
        fileForm.getMultipartFileUpload(); // always null!!!
    }
}
```

The multipartResolver

```
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver filterMultipartResolver() {
    final CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(10 * 1024 * 1024);
    multipartResolver.setMaxInMemorySize(1048576);
    multipartResolver.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return multipartResolver;
}
```

webflow configuration

```
@Configuration
public class WebFlowConfig extends AbstractFlowConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    TilesViewResolver viewResolver;

    @Bean
    public FlowDefinitionRegistry flowRegistry() {
        return getFlowDefinitionRegistryBuilder()
            .setFlowBuilderServices(flowBuilderServices())
            .setBasePath("/WEB-INF/flows/")
            .addFlowLocation("signup.xml", UrlMap.SIGNUP_WEBFLOW)
            .addFlowLocation("user-edit.xml", UrlMap.PROFILE_EDIT_WEBFLOW)
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public FlowExecutor flowExecutor() {
        return getFlowExecutorBuilder(flowRegistry()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public FlowHandlerAdapter flowHandlerAdapter() {
        final FlowHandlerAdapter flowHandlerAdapter = new FlowHandlerAdapter();
        flowHandlerAdapter.setFlowExecutor(flowExecutor());
        return flowHandlerAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public FlowHandlerMapping flowHandlerMapping() {
        final FlowHandlerMapping flowHandlerMapping = new FlowHandlerMapping();
        flowHandlerMapping.setFlowRegistry(flowRegistry());
        // this has to be less than -1
        flowHandlerMapping.setOrder(-2);
        return flowHandlerMapping;
    }

    @Bean
    public MvcViewFactoryCreator mvcViewFactoryCreator() {
        final MvcViewFactoryCreator mvcViewFactoryCreator = new MvcViewFactoryCreator();
        final List<ViewResolver> viewResolvers = Collections.singletonList(viewResolver);
        mvcViewFactoryCreator.setViewResolvers(viewResolvers);
        return mvcViewFactoryCreator;
    }

    @Bean
    public FlowBuilderServices flowBuilderServices() {
        return getFlowBuilderServicesBuilder().setViewFactoryCreator(mvcViewFactoryCreator())
            .setValidator(localValidatorFactoryBean()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }
}
```

Inside Tomcat's `context.xml` I already added `allowCasualMultipartParsing="true"`

Debugging the application I can see the file data inside the request, and I can get it if I try to post the form to a normal controller.

I tried also to remove Spring Security but it still didn't work inside Spring WebFlow.

In the requestParameters object there are only 3 objects:

- execution
- _eventid_forward
- _csrf

There are some relevant rows in the logs

```
DEBUG 2015-03-13 18:03:15,053: org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter - Using MultipartResolver 'filterMultipartResolver' for MultipartFilter
DEBUG 2015-03-13 18:03:15,053: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'filterMultipartResolver'
DEBUG 2015-03-13 18:03:15,053: org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter - Resolving multipart request [/registrazione] with MultipartFilter
DEBUG 2015-03-13 18:03:15,060: org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver - Found multipart file [multipartFileUpload] of size 469217 bytes with original filename [PoliziaMunicipale.png], stored in memory
....
DEBUG 2015-03-13 18:03:15,072: org.springframework.binding.mapping.impl.DefaultMapper - Beginning mapping between source [org.springframework.webflow.core.collection.LocalParameterMap] and target [it.openex.pmcommonw.form.FileForm]
DEBUG 2015-03-13 18:03:15,072: org.springframework.binding.mapping.impl.DefaultMapping - Adding mapping result [TargetAccessError@34bc31ea mapping = parameter:'execution' -> execution, code = 'propertyNotFound', error = true, errorCause = org.springframework.binding.expression.PropertyNotFoundException: Property not found, originalValue = 'e1s2', mappedValue = [null]]
DEBUG 2015-03-13 18:03:15,072: org.springframework.binding.mapping.impl.DefaultMapper - Completing mapping between source [org.springframework.webflow.core.collection.LocalParameterMap] and target [it.openex.pmcommonw.form.FileForm]; total mappings = 1; total errors = 1
```

The `multipartFileUpload` property is not binded in the `FileForm` bean.

I'm not sure if it's useful, but inside `org.springframework.webflow.context.servlet.HttpServletRequestParameterMap` at line 52

```
if (request instanceof MultipartHttpServletRequest) {
        // ... process multipart data
    }
```

it fails the check because the request is an instance of `org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$Servlet3SaveToSessionRequestWrapper`

### Update 1

I can confirm that multipartRequest.getFile("file") also works.

I can't enable the `org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter` filter though.

If it's enabled the multipartRequest is an instance of `StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest` containing a `Servlet3SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper`, wrapping a `Servlet3SaveToSessionRequestWrapper`, finally containing an unreachable `DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest` with the multipartFile I need, but I can't get it.

Disabling it I'm able to get it because multipartRequest became an instance of  `DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest`, but there's no file validation and the maxUploadSize limit of `CommonsMultipartResolver` is not respected.

Plus if Tomcat launches an exception because the file is too big for Tomcat's maxPostSize limit, the exception is caught by my `CustomAccessDeniedHandler` because its type is `org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException`, and the error message is `Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.`.

Looking at the request object I can see the original Tomcat exception `org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException`. It seems like there's nothing to handle it properly, but, as I said, if I enable the MultipartFilter I can't get the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We ran into the same problems, since we use Spring Security 4.xx in our web application.
The Problem is that a `org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$Servlet3SaveToSessionRequestWrapper` isn't instance of `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest` but it contains one. A cast to won't work and `ClassCastException` will occur.

Thats the reason why

```
if (request instanceof MultipartHttpServletRequest) {
    // ... process multipart data
}
```

never can be `true`.

The idea was to create a `org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest` from the native `HttpServletRequest` and it works.

In our WebApp we use Pojo Actions indicated in [Spring Webflow documentation Section 6.5.1. Invoking a POJO action](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.4.0.RELEASE/reference/html/actions.html#d4e1062).

Our Workaround:

PojoAction.java

```
public String fileUpload(RequestContext requestContext) {
    final ServletExternalContext context = (ServletExternalContext) requestContext.getExternalContext();
    final MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = new StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest((HttpServletRequest)context.getNativeRequest());
    final File file = multipartRequest.getFile("file");
    fileUploadHandler.processFile(file); //do something with the submitted file
}
```

In flow.xml we have an action state like this:

```
<action-state id="upload-action">
    <evaluate expression="pojoAction.uploadFile(flowRequestContext)"/>
    <transition to="show"/>
</action-state>
```

In this case the binding to a model is not needed.
I hope it helps!

**According to Update 1**

In web.xml the CSRF-Protection Filter must declared before SpringSecurityFilterChain.

In our application the web.xml looks like this

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>csrfFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>csrfFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
     </filter-mapping>

     <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
           org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
      </filter>
      <filter-mapping>
         <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
         <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
         <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
         <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
      </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks, following your suggestion I was able to make it work. Your code for `PojoAction.java` is slightly incorrect though. It should be 
`final MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = new StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest((HttpServletRequest) context.getNativeRequest());
  final MultipartFile multipartFileUpload = multipartRequest.getMultiFileMap().getFirst("multipartFileUpload");`.

Comment: Plus I had to remove the MultipartFilter indicated [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.0.RC2/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-multipartfilter), otherwise it wouldn't work.

Comment: Thx for your suggestions. I fixed it. Sorry for that.
`multipartRequest.getFile("file")` should also work.
The multipart filter indicated [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.0.RC2/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-multipartfilter) works in our web application with enabled CSRF-Protection.

Comment: Are u using `CommonsMultipartResolver` with ServletApi 3.0? Maybe you can use the `StandardServletMultipartResolver` as described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-multipart-resolver-standard).

Comment: Yes, it was it! Thank you so much!! Sadly now I have another problem posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29107666/how-to-handle-multipartexception-in-spring)

Comment: Dario and @Thomas, thanks for the great writeups for getting this to work. However, I'm having issues with UTF-8 on forms that have a file - the characters get mangled. If I use CommonsResolver it doesn't happen, but it does if I use StandardResolver. I've followed the suggestions to set Tomcat 8 to UTF-8 encoding and all of the other things you're to do for UTF-8 (encodingFilter, jsp header settings, etc.)  but it still doesn't work with the StandardsResolver. Did either of you run into the same issue?

Comment: Dario and @ThomasHaarbach, as a follow-up I did finally get it to work with the CommonsResolver. I found a way to cast the RequestContext from webflow - see the question/answer here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35281868). It's not pretty but it works.