# How to handle MultipartException in Spring

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-security, spring-webflow-2

My configuration is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037596/file-upload-using-spring-webflow-2-4-0-parameter-not-binded).

I made some modifications according to the answer in that post.

filterMultipartResolver

```
@Bean
public StandardServletMultipartResolver filterMultipartResolver() {
    return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
}
```

AppInitializer

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(final ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        // Create the 'root' Spring application context
        final WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
        // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
        final Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        dispatcher.setMultipartConfig(getMultipartConfigElement());
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }

    private static AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() {
        final AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(AppConfig.class);
        return context;
    }

    private static MultipartConfigElement getMultipartConfigElement(){
        return new MultipartConfigElement(Props.FILE_TMP_DIRECTORY, 3 * 1024 * 1024, 3 * 1024 * 1024, 3 * 1024 * 1024);
    }
}
```

I followed the suggestions from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856254/how-to-nicely-handle-file-upload-maxuploadsizeexceededexception-with-spring-secu), and included this `MultipartExceptionHandler`

```
public class MultipartExceptionHandler extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MultipartExceptionHandler.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (final MultipartException me) {
            log.error(me.getMessage());
            response.sendRedirect(UrlUtils.buildFullRequestUrl(request) + "&error=size-limit");
        }
    }
}
```

registering it in

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    protected void beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(final ServletContext servletContext) {
        insertFilters(servletContext, new MultipartExceptionHandler());
        insertFilters(servletContext, new MultipartFilter());
    }
}
```

When I try to upload a file exceeding the maximum size this is what I get in the logs

```
DEBUG 2015-03-17 19:54:18,372: org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter - Using MultipartResolver 'filterMultipartResolver' for MultipartFilter
DEBUG 2015-03-17 19:54:18,372: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'filterMultipartResolver'
DEBUG 2015-03-17 19:54:18,372: org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter - Resolving multipart request [/registrazione] with MultipartFilter
ERROR 2015-03-17 19:54:18,384: it.openex.pmfew.filters.MultipartExceptionHandler - Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (4522604) exceeds the configured maximum (3145728)
DEBUG 2015-03-17 19:54:18,386: org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter - Using MultipartResolver 'filterMultipartResolver' for MultipartFilter
DEBUG 2015-03-17 19:54:18,386: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'filterMultipartResolver'
DEBUG 2015-03-17 19:54:18,386: org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter - Resolving multipart request [/registrazione] with MultipartFilter
ERROR 2015-03-17 19:54:18,386: it.openex.pmfew.filters.MultipartExceptionHandler - Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (4522604) exceeds the configured maximum (3145728)
```

It repeats itself 7 times, and the redirect specified in the filter doesn't happen: I simply get a blank page.

I'm not sure what happens because **sometime** adding a debug breakpoint in the filter makes it work, or even adding a `Thread.sleep(100)`

### Update 1

Some more information on the issue.

Every time I restart Tomcat the filter could be called 2 times or 7 times.
There is only one POST call.

The response in chrome is `(failed) net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`.

The request is an instance of `org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade`, containing an instance of `org.apache.catalina.connector.Request`. Inside the latter the attribute `partsParseException` is carrying the exception showing in the log.
The request is identical every time.

There are 4 filters in the chain:

- MultipartExceptionHandler (the filter I added)
- `org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter`
- `org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy`
- `org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter`

I upgraded Tomcat to the last version: 8.0.20.

I tried to make a redirect to a simple url like `/`, and catching all kind of exceptions inside the filter, included the ones potentially thrown by the catch block.

The result is this

```
public class MultipartExceptionHandler extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MultipartExceptionHandler.class);
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (final MultipartException me) {
            try{
                log.error(me.getMessage());
                response.sendRedirect(UrlMap.HOME);
            } catch (final Exception e){
                log.error(e.getMessage());
            }

        }catch (final Exception e){
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

What is disturbing is that it doesn't seem to behave deterministically: using Intellij Idea, sometime if I put a breakpoint inside the catch block of `MultipartExceptionHandler' and then resume the program it works flawlessly.

If it doesn't, I just have to restart Tomcat 1 or 2 times until the trick works again.

Without the breakpoint the program never works.

### Update 2

I tested a little more the behaviour of the application.

I discovered that simply it works out of the box every now and then, without restarting Tomcat or making anything fancy.

It's a matter of retrying to upload the file until it goes well, pushing the browser back button to return to the upload page in case of error.

It works 1 out of 4-5 times, without any apparent repeating pattern.

This is the stacktrace if it fails. In the logs it is repeated 2 times consecutively and there is nothing else after it.

```
INFO  2015-03-18 12:21:59,870: it.openex.pmfew.filters.MultipartExceptionHandler - #############################
INFO  2015-03-18 12:21:59,870: it.openex.pmfew.filters.MultipartExceptionHandler - /registrazione?execution=e3s2
INFO  2015-03-18 12:21:59,870: it.openex.pmfew.filters.MultipartExceptionHandler - #############################
DEBUG 2015-03-18 12:21:59,870: org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter - Using MultipartResolver 'filterMultipartResolver' for MultipartFilter
DEBUG 2015-03-18 12:21:59,870: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'filterMultipartResolver'
DEBUG 2015-03-18 12:21:59,870: org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter - Resolving multipart request [/registrazione] with MultipartFilter
ERROR 2015-03-18 12:21:59,870: it.openex.pmfew.filters.MultipartExceptionHandler - Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (4522604) exceeds the configured maximum (3145728)
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (4522604) exceeds the configured maximum (3145728)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter.doFilterInternal(MultipartFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at it.openex.pmfew.filters.MultipartExceptionHandler.doFilterInternal(MultipartExceptionHandler.java:29)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (4522604) exceeds the configured maximum (3145728)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2792)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2636)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParts(RequestFacade.java:1083)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:84)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (4522604) exceeds the configured maximum (3145728)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:811)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:256)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2725)
    ... 30 more
```

Instead, if it goes well, the stacktrace is showed only once and than this is appended  (I removed some parts because of the size limit of the post)

```
INFO  2015-03-18 12:20:38,789: it.openex.pmfew.filters.MultipartExceptionHandler - #############################
INFO  2015-03-18 12:20:38,789: it.openex.pmfew.filters.MultipartExceptionHandler - Url called -> /registrazione?execution=e1s2&error=size-limit
INFO  2015-03-18 12:20:38,789: it.openex.pmfew.filters.MultipartExceptionHandler - #############################
DEBUG 2015-03-18 12:20:38,789: org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter - Using MultipartResolver 'filterMultipartResolver' for MultipartFilter
DEBUG 2015-03-18 12:20:38,789: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'filterMultipartResolver'
DEBUG 2015-03-18 12:20:38,789: org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter - Request [/registrazione] is not a multipart request
DEBUG 2015-03-18 12:20:38,789: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /registrazione?execution=e1s2&error=size-limit at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
DEBUG 2015-03-18 12:20:38,789: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /registrazione?execution=e1s2&error=size-limit at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
DEBUG 2015-03-18 12:20:38,789: org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@2fabad6. A new one will be created.
DEBUG 2015-03-18 12:20:38,789: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /registrazione?execution=e1s2&error=size-limit at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
DEBUG 2015-03-18 12:20:38,789: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /registrazione?execution=e1s2&error=size-limit at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CharacterEncodingFilter'
DEBUG 2015-03-18 12:20:38,789: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /registrazione?execution=e1s2&error=size-limit at position 5 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
DEBUG 2015-03-18 12:20:38,789: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /registrazione?execution=e1s2&error=size-limit at position 6 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
DEBUG 2015-03-18 12:20:38,789: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /registrazione?execution=e1s2&error=size-limit at position 7 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG 2015-03-18 12:20:38,789: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /registrazione?execution=e1s2&error=size-limit at position 8 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
DEBUG 2015-03-18 12:20:38,789: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /registrazione?execution=e1s2&error=size-limit at position 9 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
DEBUG 2015-03-18 12:20:38,789: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /registrazione?execution=e1s2&error=size-limit at position 10 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG 2015-03-18 12:20:38,789: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /registrazione?execution=e1s2&error=size-limit at position 11 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
DEBUG 2015-03-18 12:20:38,789: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /registrazione?execution=e1s2&error=size-limit at position 12 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
DEBUG 2015-03-18 12:20:38,789: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /registrazione?execution=e1s2&error=size-limit at position 13 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
DEBUG 2015-03-18 12:20:38,789: org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /registrazione?execution=e1s2&error=size-limit; Attributes: [permitAll]
DEBUG 2015-03-18 12:20:38,789: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /registrazione?execution=e1s2&error=size-limit reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
DEBUG 2015-03-18 12:20:38,789: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'DispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/registrazione]
DEBUG 2015-03-18 12:20:38,789: org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping - Mapping request with URI '/registrazione' to flow with id 'registrazione'
DEBUG 2015-03-18 12:20:38,789: org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl - Resuming flow execution with key 'e1s2
DEBUG 2015-03-18 12:20:38,790: org.springframework.webflow.conversation.impl.SessionBindingConversationManager - Locking conversation 1
DEBUG 2015-03-18 12:20:38,790: org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.impl.DefaultFlowExecutionRepository - Getting flow execution with key 'e1s2'
DEBUG 2015-03-18 12:20:38,790: org.springframework.webflow.definition.registry.FlowDefinitionRegistryImpl - Getting FlowDefinition with id 'registrazione'
DEBUG 2015-03-18 12:20:38,809: org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.impl.DefaultFlowExecutionRepository - Putting flow execution '[FlowExecutionImpl@23da7555 flow = 'registrazione', flowSessions = list[[FlowSessionImpl@4c63c9fd flow = 'registrazione', state = 'companyLogo', scope = map['viewScope' -> map['fileForm' -> it.openex.pmcommonw.form.FileForm@ae6eeae], 'menuDTO' -> list[it.openex.pmfew.dtos.MenuEntryDTO@2fcdd386, it.openex.pmfew.dtos.MenuEntryDTO@3ba665a6, it.openex.pmfew.dtos.MenuEntryDTO@5767063d], 'userCompanyInfoForm' -> it.openex.pmcommonw.form.UserCompanyInfoForm@6ac911e1]]]]' into repository
DEBUG 2015-03-18 12:20:38,810: org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.impl.DefaultFlowExecutionRepository - Adding snapshot to group with id 2
DEBUG 2015-03-18 12:20:38,813: org.springframework.webflow.conversation.impl.SessionBindingConversationManager - Unlocking conversation 1
DEBUG 2015-03-18 12:20:38,813: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
DEBUG 2015-03-18 12:20:38,813: org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
```

### Update 3

Until now I tried to upload a file 4.5MB large.

Using a 30MB file instead it never works.

### Update 4

Looking at the POST request in Chrome's Developer Tools, on the Timing tab, I can see the request was stalled. [More info about this state.](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network#resource-network-timing)

Firefox works every time with the 4.5MB large file, redirecting correctly to the error page. With a larger file (say 7MB) it doesn't work and the browser returns the message

```
The connection was reset

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
```

### Update 5

Switching inside `MultipartExceptionHandler` the row

```
response.sendRedirect(UrlUtils.buildFullRequestUrl(request) + "&error=size-limit");
```

with

```
final RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/");
requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

it works 3 out of 4 times in Chrome, and with large files it fails always as usual. Nothing changes in the logs.

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but could that have been that Tomcat server was cancelling the request if it was too big?  With Spring Boot 2 you could set following property: server.tomcat.max-swallow-size=100MB 
See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49098174/519035

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like multiple requests. According to the log the `MultipartExceptionHandler` is called when a Exception occurs.

> Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException:

Maybe you can add a logger after `protected void doFilterInternal(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final FilterChain filterChain)`, set an break point here and check the request. It's possible that the request is null or something else because of

> Could not parse multipart servlet request; ... the request was rejected because its size ...

and in this case `UrlUtils.buildFullRequestUrl(request)`will also throw a exception which is not catched.

```
public final class UrlUtils {
    public static String buildFullRequestUrl(HttpServletRequest r) {
         return buildFullRequestUrl(r.getScheme(), r.getServerName(), r.getServerPort(), r.getRequestURI(),
                 r.getQueryString());
    }
...
```

Try to set the redirect uri manually like `response.sendRedirect(uri + "&error=size-limit")`. This implies that the response must not be null.

Try to write a test for your file upload with mock requests and mock exception and assert the expected redirect uri.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I updated the question according to your suggestions.

Comment: Can you add a full stacktrace from you logs? See also the catalina log.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same situation: my MultipartExceptionHandler is called multiple times (3) even if the request is 1 (I can see it into my browser inspector).

This drive me to the error: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

```
public class MultipartExceptionHandler extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());    

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (MaxUploadSizeExceededException e) {
            handle(request, response, e);
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            if(e.getRootCause() instanceof MaxUploadSizeExceededException) {
                handle(request, response, (MaxUploadSizeExceededException) e.getRootCause());
            } else {
                throw e;
            }
        } finally {
            String url = Utils.buildFullRequestUrl(request);
            log.debug("URL: " + url);
        }
    }

    private void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, MaxUploadSizeExceededException e) throws IOException {
        String redirect = UrlUtils.buildFullRequestUrl(request) + "?upload-error=true";
        response.sendRedirect(redirect);
    }


}
```

Have you got any suggestion?

Thanks.

**SOLVED**

In my case the problem was that I've missed to set the Tomcat **maxSwallowSize** parameter.