# How to handle Multipart Exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I am building a website for uploading pictures. I am using Spring Boot, eureka and zuul proxy.I am trying to limit the size of the user uploaded pictures. When the picture exceeds the limit it should return some message, but instead it throws a `MultipartException`. The problem is I don't know
how to handle it. I have found a lot of examples on the net, but none of them worked for me. I found an example with servlet filter, but with no luck. I have also tried with `ControllerAdvice`, yet I still can't handle it.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionController {

    @ExceptionHandler(FileUploadBase.FileSizeLimitExceededException.class)
    public String uploadedAFileTooLarge(FileUploadBase.FileSizeLimitExceededException e) {
        return "File upload error";
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(MultipartException.class)
    public String handleFileException(HttpServletRequest request, Throwable ex) {
        return "File upload error";
    }
}
```

this is the application.yml:

```
spring:
  http:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 5Mb
      max-request-size: 10Mb
```

This is the exception I am getting:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (41464012) exceeds the configured maximum (10485760)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:726) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:394) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:395) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:254) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:175) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (41464012) exceeds the configured maximum (10485760)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:111) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:85) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:76) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1099) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:932) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (41464012) exceeds the configured maximum (10485760)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2871) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3176) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1110) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:381) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:70) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (41464012) exceeds the configured maximum (10485760)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:811) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:256) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:280) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2801) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
```

If any other information is needed I would be happy to give it to you.

Comment: Were you able to catch that exception in your main class ?

Comment: Yes, I already know the reason, the problem is I don't know how to handle the exception. I need to be able to return a message from the catch block and warn the user, that he should upload a smaller picture

Comment: No, I am not able to catch it :(

Comment: I think that you need to create a custom exception handler class and then pass it in the @ExceptionHandler annotation for the class which handles the file upload. Inside that class, you will be able to check the type of exception and then have the code to alert the user.

Comment: it is `SizeLimitExceededException` Can you increase your multipart file size

Comment: No, the trick is not to increase the limit, but to catch the exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the exception you can handle is java.lang.IllegalStateException. The FileUploadBase.FileSizeLimitExceededException.class is not thrown. Maybe because it is an inner class?

To make it work I also had to to make a change in Tomcat's server.xml.

The default behaviour of Tomcat is to disconnect a client that sends (uploads) too much data. After the connection is closed, you cannot send any data back the client.

You can instruct Tomcat to continue reading the request, even if the size of the request has exceeded the limit, by adding `maxSwallowSize = "-1"` to the connector in server.xml.

For a complete and detailed explanation on how to handle the Exception in Spring, see: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-maxuploadsizeexceeded

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a method in your exception handler class like below :

```
@ExceptionHandler(MultipartException.class)
public String handleMultipartException(MultipartException e, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", e.getCause().getMessage());
    return "redirect:/uploadStatus";
}
```

You can have another page to show the upload status like this :

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Upload Status</h1>
<h2>Message : ${message}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

The same is given [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-file-upload-example/) with more details.

Comment: No, unfortunately this did not solve the issue. I am getting the same exception and still not able to catch it. I have some doubts that the exception is thrown before the request has reached the dispatcher servlet. Therefore the exceptionhandler isn't called because at the point the exception is thrown the target controller has yet to be determined

Comment: Are you sure that the exception does not reach the ExceptionHandler ? Try adding a sysout and check whether it is printing in the console, so that we can be sure that the exception does not reach the handler.

Comment: also make sure your exception handler is included in the component scan package.

Comment: I tried with printing in the console, but it did not print. I also added a break point inside the ExceptionHandler, yet it did not reach

Comment: I think the exception handler is not configured for component scanning. Are other exceptions thrown caught by the exception handler class ? Try to throw a different exception for which you handle it in the exception handler and see if it getting caught ? You can then confirm if your handler class is not configured for component scan or not.

Comment: It should be configured correctly, as all other exceptions are being caught without a problem. Only this exception is not

Comment: There seems to be two types of `MultipartResolver` - `StandardServletMultipartResolver` and `CommonsMultipartResolver`. The exception handler has to use the correct class in order to catch it. Please check if you are using the right one. More info here - http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartResolver.html

Comment: Also `There is no default resolver implementation used for Spring DispatcherServlets, as an application might choose to parse its multipart requests itself. To define an implementation, create a bean with the id "multipartResolver" in a DispatcherServlet's application context. Such a resolver gets applied to all requests handled by that DispatcherServlet. `