# Issue with Spring Security, Spring Webflow, file uploads and UTF-8

Tags: file-upload, utf-8, spring-security, spring-webflow-2

I have a problem very similar to the one described here: [File Upload using Spring WebFlow 2.4.0, parameter not binded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037596/file-upload-using-spring-webflow-2-4-0-parameter-not-binded), but that one didn't mention anything about UTF-8 issues.  I'm using Spring Framework 4.1.6, Spring Security 4.0.2 and Spring Webflow 2.4.2.

It revolves around `StandardServletMultipartResolver` vs. `CommonsMultipartResolver` as far as I can tell, but I'm not sure.  If I use `CommonsMultipartResolver` I can upload files on any page except for Webflow pages fine and UTF-8 encoding works as well on all pages. However on the Webflow pages an exception is thrown trying to access the file . If I use `StandardServletMultipartResolver` then all of the file uploads work, including Webflow, but on any page that has a UTF-8 character, e.g., caractère, I get garbage.

The wierd thing is I can see in FireBug that the file is being posted when I use the commons resolver. Also, if I debug the `RequestContext` coming from Webflow I can also see the file buried 4 levels deep in requests. The code for the common resolver (see end of post for the standard resolver code):

```
public FileResult uploadFile(Recipe recipe, RequestContext requestContext) {
    ServletExternalContext context = (ServletExternalContext) requestContext.getExternalContext();
    MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = new DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest((HttpServletRequest)context.getNativeRequest());
    MultipartFile file = multipartRequest.getFile("file");
```

So, is this a Spring Security issue or a Spring Webflow problem?  I suspect the commons resolver would work if I could cast the RequestContext above correctly, but I've tried numerous combinations with no luck. Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Here are some relevant configurations and code:

**WebMvcConfig**

```
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver filterMultipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    resolver.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return resolver;
}
```

**SecurityConfig**

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);

    http
    //.csrf().disable()
    .addFilterBefore(characterEncodingFilter, CsrfFilter.class)
    ...more settings...
```

**SecurityInitializer**

```
@Override
protected void beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
    insertFilters(servletContext, new MultipartFilter());
}
```

**Webflow Action**

```
<action-state id="uploadFile">
    <evaluate expression="fileActions.uploadFile(recipe, flowRequestContext)"/>
    <transition to="review"/>
</action-state>
```

**Upload file method**

```
public FileResult uploadFile(Recipe recipe, RequestContext requestContext) {
    ServletExternalContext context = (ServletExternalContext) requestContext.getExternalContext();
    MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = new StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest((HttpServletRequest)context.getNativeRequest());
    MultipartFile file = multipartRequest.getFile("file");
    ...rest of code to save the file...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you *can* cast the RequestContext to get at the underlying `MultipartHttpServletRequest` but it's not pretty. Here's what I ended up with:

**Upload file method**

```
public FileResult uploadFile(Recipe recipe, RequestContext requestContext) {
    logger.debug("uploadFile");

    ServletExternalContext context = (ServletExternalContext) requestContext.getExternalContext();
    SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper wrapper1 = (SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper)context.getNativeRequest();
    HttpServletRequestWrapper wrapper2 = (HttpServletRequestWrapper)wrapper1.getRequest();
    FirewalledRequest firewall = (FirewalledRequest)wrapper2.getRequest();
    MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = (DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest)firewall.getRequest();
    MultipartFile file = multipartRequest.getFile("file");
    ...rest of code to save the file...
```

Using this I get to keep the `CommonsMultipartResolver`, all file uploads in the app work whether Webflow or not, and I have no issues with UTF-8 and character mangling.

I'm not particularly happy with this solution (even though it works) since it's dependent upon a specific nesting of requests that could change in the future(?).  I'm be interested if anyone else has run into the same UTF-8 issue and how they solved it, but for now I'm going to test the heck out of this and move on.